# PackageManager getApplicationIcon Blurred Images

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Whenever I pull all icons using PackageManager's getApplicationIcon(PackageName) I get an icon which is blurred at even a 70x70 ImageView. 
Is there anyway to get a bigger, clearer icon of the Installed packages?

Comment: im not sure but i think icons are up to 48 before it gets blurred..

Comment: Yeah i figured that much, but i've noticed the Android Default launcher is able to display a much clearer icon...